# I Cannot Fetch List<String> from Firebase RealtimeDatabase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I have my data from Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

This is my Model and it's fromMap function:

```
class ProjectModel {
  String projectId;
  String projectName;
  String projecctDescription;
  String startDate;
  String endDate;
  String projectStatus;
  String managerId;
  String leaderId;
  List<String> projectMembers;
}

factory ProjectModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ProjectModel(
        projectId: map['projectId'] as String,
        projectName: map['projectName'] as String,
        projecctDescription: map['projecctDescription'] as String,
        startDate: map['startDate'] as String,
        endDate: map['endDate'] as String,
        projectStatus: map['projectStatus'] as String,
        managerId: map['managerId'] as String,
        leaderId: map['leaderId'] as String,
        projectMembers:
            List<String>.from((map['projectMembers'] as List<String>)));
  }
```

And then I've tried to fetch it by this code:

```
projectsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('projects');
projectsRef?.onValue.listen((event) {
        setState(() {
          projectsMap = Map.from(event.snapshot.value as dynamic);
          for (var project in projectsMap.values) {
            ProjectModel projectModel =
                ProjectModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>.from(project));
          }
        });
      });
```

However i cannot get the ProjectModel excepted for removing the list projectMembers
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcvoK.png)

i expect that i can fetch ProjectModel but keeping the list projectMembers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "However i cannot get the ProjectModel excepted for removing the list projectMembers". Is there an error message? Or some logging output that we can see?

Comment: I don't know how to expain but it worked and I get my ProjectModel by removing "as List<String>" in the line "projectMembers:
            List<String>.from((map['projectMembers'] as List<String>)));"